# Dynamically populate "value" in sql query

Tags: jquery, sql, jsp, sqlplus

I have just started learning SQL, and this is a purely learning based question.

Let's say I have a 3 dependent dropdowns, with fields category, type, name respectively. 
Now if a user selects the category: food, type: fruit and name: apple, I want to filter my SQL table data based on this. 
I came up with using

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE category = 'food' , type = 'fruit', name = 'apple';`

However, I do not know how can I dynamically populate the query with the values selected by a user in the dropdown list.

Please help, I am a complete newbie and do not know what to search regarding the same. Any kind of help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I implemented a form and have fields in this form which the user can fill. Now when user fills the field and clicks on submit, these fields are then passed on to the next page as URL parameters. I can query the URL string and get the fields into a variable. So now I have a variable "category1" whose value = food. 
What  I wish to do now is, make a SQL Query such that:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = category1`

That is, here category1 is a variable. So how do I include a variable in the sql query.

Thanks

Comment: SQL deals with **tables**.  The rest is application domain.

Comment: I understand that, But how can I dynamically populate the query with values in the where clause ? That is where I am stuck at rn

Comment: Your application should have a compatible SQL driver and use the appropriate syntax.

Comment: Okay, I thing the question was not very clear. 

so **UPDATE**:

I implemented a form and have fields in this form which the user can fill. Now when user fills the field and clicks on submit, these fields are then passed on to the next page as URL parameters. I can query the URL string and get the fields into a variable. So now I have a variable "category1" whose value = food. 
What  I wish to do now is, make a SQL Query such that: 

```SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = category1 ```

That is, here category1 is a variable. So how do I include a variable in the sql query.

Comment: It depends on your platform that implements the form.  What is the web framework you use?

Comment: It is a JSP file.

Comment: Then you need [`jdbc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). To avoid SQL injection it's better to use [`prepared statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). General architecture for JSP+MySQL: https://www.9lessons.info/2008/09/jsp-login-page-to-connect-mysql-atabase.html